# Node.js Google Calendar Passport OAuth issue

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm having an issue authenticating with Google Calendar in my Node.js app.

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, and GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL have all been setup correctly and have been triple checked. Authorised redirect URIs have also been checked and rechecked.

Errors I'm getting on local and production:

```
2024-03-06 12:51:09 info: Deserializing user with ID:
2024-03-06 12:51:09 info: User deserialized successfully:
2024-03-06 12:51:09 info: State parameter from Google:
2024-03-06 12:51:09 info: Entered /auth/google/callback route. Processing...
2024-03-06 12:51:09 info: Initiating Passport authentication...
2024-03-06 12:51:11 info: Passport authentication processed.
2024-03-06 12:51:11 error: Passport authentication error:
2024-03-06 12:51:11 error: Invalid Credentials
2024-03-06 12:51:11 error: Error occurred on route /google-calendar/auth/google/callback - Method: GET
```

Here is the code in question:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const Email = require("../models/email");
const {
  getCalendarEvent,
  createGoogleCalendarEvent,
} = require("../calendarEvents");
const logger = require("../logger");
const logInfo = logger.logInfo;
const logError = logger.logError;

// Setup Passport
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL,
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      logInfo("Entered GoogleStrategy callback");

      // Add detailed logging for received tokens and profile
      logInfo("Received Access Token: ", accessToken);
      logInfo("Received Refresh Token: ", refreshToken);
      logInfo("Received Profile: ", profile);

      // Check if accessToken is a non-empty string
      if (typeof accessToken !== "string" || !accessToken) {
        logError("Access token is either missing or not a string.");
        return done(new Error("No access token received"), null);
      }

      // Check if refreshToken is a non-empty string
      if (typeof refreshToken !== "string" || !refreshToken) {
        logError("Refresh token is either missing or not a string.");
        return done(new Error("No refresh token received"), null);
      }

      let user;
      try {
        user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { googleId: profile.id },
          { googleId: profile.id },
          { upsert: true, new: true },
        );
      } catch (err) {
        logError("Error querying the database for user:", err);
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        logError("Unexpected error: No user returned after findOneAndUpdate.");
        return done(
          new Error("Unexpected error during user retrieval or creation"),
          null,
        );
      }
      logInfo("User retrieved or created successfully with ID:", user._id);

      // Before saving tokens, refresh if needed
      const validAccessToken = await checkAndRefreshToken(
        user,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
      );
      accessToken = validAccessToken || accessToken;

      // Save the tokens to the user
      try {
        await user.setGoogleTokens({ accessToken, refreshToken });
        logInfo(
          "Access and refresh tokens saved successfully for user:",
          user._id,
        );
      } catch (err) {
        logError("Error while saving tokens for user:", err);
      }

      logInfo("Exiting GoogleStrategy callback");
      done(null, user);
    },
  ),
);

async function checkAndRefreshToken(
  user,
  currentAccessToken,
  currentRefreshToken,
) {
  try {
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    const EXPIRY_WINDOW = 300; // 5 minutes

    if (
      !user.googleTokens ||
      !user.googleTokens.expiryDate ||
      currentTime > user.googleTokens.expiryDate - EXPIRY_WINDOW
    ) {
      const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL,
      );

      // Add detailed logging
      logInfo("Refreshing Google access token...");

      oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: currentRefreshToken });
      const newAccessToken = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();

      if (!newAccessToken || !newAccessToken.token) {
        throw new Error("Failed to refresh the access token");
      }

      return newAccessToken.token;
    }
    return currentAccessToken;
  } catch (err) {
    logError("Error in token refresh:", err);
    throw err;
  }
}

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  logInfo("Serializing user with ID:", user.id);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  logInfo("Deserializing user with ID:", id);
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (user) {
      logInfo("User deserialized successfully:", user._id);
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      logError("Failed to deserialize user with ID:", id);
      done(new Error("Failed to deserialize user"), null);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logError("Error during deserialization:", err);
    done(err, null);
  }
});

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("google-calendar");
});

// The route to redirect the user to the Google consent screen
router.get(
  "/connect",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    ],
    accessType: "offline",
    prompt: "consent",
  }),
);

// The route where Google redirects the user after the consent screen
router.get("/auth/google/callback", function (req, res, next) {
  // Log the state parameter, which can be helpful to trace back any CSRF issues
  logInfo("State parameter from Google:", req.query.state);

  // Initial Entry Point
  logInfo("Entered /auth/google/callback route. Processing...");

  // Before Passport Authentication
  logInfo("Initiating Passport authentication...");

  passport.authenticate("google", function (err, user, info) {
    // Enhanced logging
    if (info) {
      logInfo("Additional Passport Info:", JSON.stringify(info, null, 2));
    }

    // Log after passport authentication has processed
    logInfo("Passport authentication processed.");

    if (err) {
      // 3. Inside the Authentication Callback - Error Scenario
      logError("Passport authentication error:", {
        errorMessage: err.message,
        errorStack: err.stack,
        additionalInfo: info,
        error: err,
      });
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      // User not found scenario
      logWarn("No user data retrieved during Passport authentication.");
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }

    // Successful authentication
    logInfo("User authenticated successfully:", {
      userId: user.id,
      username: user.username,
    });

    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        logError(
          "Error during the login phase after Passport authentication:",
          err,
        );
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.redirect("/users/" + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware stack on the `GET /auth/google/callback` route looks incorrect; `passport.authenticate` returns a middleware handler, if you want to add further middleware to your route you add an additional handler to your stack.

e.g.

```js
router.get("/auth/google/callback", function (req, res, next) {
  // Log the state parameter, which can be helpful to trace back any CSRF issues
  logInfo("State parameter from Google:", req.query.state);

  // Initial Entry Point
  logInfo("Entered /auth/google/callback route. Processing...");

  // Before Passport Authentication
  logInfo("Initiating Passport authentication...");
  },
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }),
  function ({user, ...req}, res, next) {
  //...
```

Comment: If this isn't the right answer, can you expand on what you're hoping to find with the bounty?

Comment: @Raydot I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The example is far from the clearest code I've browsed. There are some redundant checks and the Google Passport strategy isn't really doing much and I'd remove it, especially considering the `googleapis` package already required is of much better quality and implements almost everything you need with their [oauth2 client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/oauth2/index.html).

Comment: Ha, no, didn't mean you @Andrew Gillis, I meant the OP!  Sorry that was unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue with authenticating with Google Calendar in your Node.js app, specifically the "Invalid Credentials" error, might be rooted in several areas based on your code and the logs you've provided.

Your code checks and possibly refreshes the access token if needed. However, the error might still occur before this logic is effectively utilized. Consider verifying:

Ensure the flow that acquires the initial access and refresh tokens works correctly. The "Invalid Credentials" error could occur if the initial tokens are not correctly obtained or saved.
Refresh Token Logic: Debug the checkAndRefreshToken function to ensure it correctly refreshes the token and doesn't throw an error that isn't caught or handled properly.

Your authentication scope requests both read-only access to calendar events and the ability to create events. Double-check that:

The user has given consent to the requested scopes. Lack of proper consent or revocation of previously granted consent might lead to authentication issues.
Scope Changes: If you've recently changed scopes, users might need to consent again. Make sure the prompt is set to "consent" to force re-authorization when needed, as you've done in your /connect route.

Enhance logging around the authentication flow, especially before and after the call to Google's OAuth service. Log the exact error messages and codes returned by Google APIs.

Use a tool like Postman or Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground to manually check if your GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, and refresh tokens are valid by attempting to obtain an access token.

Ensure that the passport strategy is correctly initialized and that there's no mismatch in the way the Google OAuth2 strategy expects the tokens and user profile to be handled.